# How do I share files between a host Mac OS and a guest Ubuntu via Parallels Desktop 7

Tags: macos, file-sharing, parallels, ubuntu-12.04

I chose the share option and shared the file in Mac OS, but I cannot find the file in Ubuntu 12.04.  What is the path to the shared folder from within Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

I found mine here:

```
/home/[user]/Desktop/Parallels Shared Folders/
```

Hope it works for you.